# Error in setup of tailwind css in vs code

Tags: tailwind-css

The utility `w-[calc(100%-theme('spacing[some_key][1.5]'))]` contains an invalid theme value and was not generated.

I am getting this error on running my html file and no css is working

I tried everything but unable to resolve the error.
Please help

Comment: Do you really have `some_key` in your spacing config or is it kinda "demonstration placeholder" to show that no matter the key the problem exists?

Comment: What I am trying to say is I'm pretty positive you want to use `theme('spacing[1.5]')`. But it depends on your configuration file

Comment: Solution:  https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/9694?sort=top#discussioncomment-4018020

Comment: For me, this issue got resolved by removing the node_modules folder and by regenerating the node_modules from "npm install".

Reference Link: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8650#discussioncomment-3011000

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue got resolved by removing the **node_modules** folder and by regenerating the **node_modules** from **"npm install"**.

**Reference Link:**

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8650#discussioncomment-3011000

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problems, i have all my files in one folder and i just changed the "content" line (in tailwind.config.js) to this :

```
      content: ["./*.{html,js}"],
      presets: [],
      ....
```

its work for me with faster rebuilding